# Item Drop After Enemy Death

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the revised code that is almost fully functioning. I've commented where the last couple bugs are located. Basically, the randNum is being called every frame because this code is inside of an update function. When the enemy dies, the HP value is 0 and I need to maybe reload the enemyHP to anything over 0. However, is this the best approach? Because it may alter my other enemies Hp?

The second issue is when the enemy dies, all other enemies of this type spawn an item. How do I fix it to where it only spawns on the enemy that has died? I'm thinking because my Epos variable has grabbed the components of all enemies is the problem. I think I need a better approach?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class ItemDrop : MonoBehaviour
{
  [SerializeField]
  private GameObject[] itemList; // Stores the game items
  private int itemNum; // Selects a number to choose from the itemList
  private int randNum; // chooses a random number to see if loot os dropped- Loot chance
  private Transform Epos; // enemy position


private void Start()
{

    Epos = GetComponent<Transform>();
    Debug.Log(itemList);
}
private void Update()
{
    if(EnemyDMG.enemyHP <= 0)
    {



        // This number get's called non-stop after enemy dies
        // This causes non-stop item drops
        // I need to know the logic to make this code happen only once per kill
            randNum = Random.Range(0, 101); // 100% total for determining loot chance;
            Debug.Log("Random Number is " + randNum);

        // The code below runs now and instantiates objects
        // However, all of the similar enemies that are alive drop items
         // at their location. I need to know how to make an item drop
        // only at the lace the enemy was killed
        if(randNum >= 95) // Star Tablet drop itemList[2] currently
        {

            itemNum = 2;// grabs the star tab
            Instantiate(itemList[itemNum], Epos.position, Quaternion.identity);


        }
        else if(randNum > 75 && randNum < 95) // Extra life drop itemList[1] currently
        {

            itemNum = 1;// grabs the star tab
            Instantiate(itemList[itemNum], Epos.position, Quaternion.identity);

        }
        else if(randNum > 40 && randNum <= 75)// Health Heart drop itemList[0] currently
        {

            itemNum = 0;// grabs the star tab
            Instantiate(itemList[itemNum], Epos.position, Quaternion.identity);

        }
    }
  }


 }
```

Comment: You should try to simplify your example.  If the problem really is "How do I spawn an object at a position?" that is what you should ask.  Everything about the randomness is cluttering the question.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: "Code fails" is not a helpful description of the problem. Ideally you could describe what the code is expected to do and what it actually does, e.g. if you get a compilation or run-time error and where it is located.

Comment: That is what I'm asking. How do I make the object appear? I think I'm pretty close. However, I can't remember how to properly instantiate an object. That's what I'm trying to learn here. My apologies to you guys for the confusion. I'll see if I can't do some editing for you.

Comment: I revised my Instantiate() code. That looks a little more normal to me. However, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should comment out all your code first. Then make your itemList public (temporarily). Then use the inspector to put a prefab into this array. Then in your script only leave your 'if' statement in there and Instantiate(itemList[0]...). In other words remove all possible interference and test the instantiation. Currently it looks like nothing will happen if randNum is below 40. You might want to put Debug.Log() at some places to make sure your code is executing how you think it is (if you know how to debug then that would be better).

Comment: First of all where is this `EnemyDMG` coming from? Is it a static class?  When you get a random number lower than 40 there is no drop? Add some debug lines and see please either your list is empty or you can not access `EnemyDMG` otherwise this should work

Comment: @AliKanat - EnemyDMG is my enemies damage script. Which is attached to the enemy prefabs that are in the scene. The enemyHpPass is a static variable that's set to equal the non-static enemyHp variable within the script. EnemyHp is also a private variable, so I don't know if I can set a private variable into a static variable and pass it off or not? Could this be the issue? Also note that I load my items from my camera follow script because my camera never gets destroyed so I load things to pass onto my prefabs so when they're generated, they have a reference for components. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Reasurria - That sounds like it's worth a try! I'll run some test and see what I find out and get back with you on this. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, the problem is with the variables being set to private. So I switched the enemyHP from private to public static. This works because the Debug log shows that now the randNum is activating when the enemy dies. But here's my problem now. The array on CamFollow can't be public static so I'm not sure how to load my objects into the array without using the inspector because they're prefabs and can't GameObject.FindWithTag() or anything like that. So I need some help here. How do I load these prefab items into a list without using the inspector?

Comment: @AntonioTorro what about `var obj = Instantiate(itemList[itemNum],Epos.position, Quaternion.identity) ;` (pass the position like this btw) and `targetList.Add(obj)` ?

Comment: [SerializeField]
    private GameObject[] itemList; // Stores the game items I was able to put the list on the script and still fill the prefabs. I deleted the enemy prefab and dragged it back in and the list was still populated. This is good! However, now when I kill an enemy, the randNum continuously runs and when I kill an enemy all enemies of that type drop items as they move. What condition do I need to make so the randNum only occurs once upon enemy death? And why are the other enemies dropping when I kill one enemy?

Comment: I have revised my code in the main topic and have commented at where I'm having the known issues. There are two more kinks to work out and it will be good to go! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to get the code working I had to remove the code from inside of the Update(). I then created a function and pasted my code inside of it DropItem(). I then had to remove the enemyHP <=0 out of the code altogether.

Next step was to go into my EnemyDamage script create a new variable private ItemDrop getItem, and finally, on the inside of the OnCollisionEnter2D() I added a quick check for ItemDrop upon enemy death. Source code below.

The final completed and working code is:

```
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;


 public class ItemDrop : MonoBehaviour
 {
 [SerializeField]
private GameObject[] itemList; // Stores the game items
private int itemNum; // Selects a number to choose from the itemList
private int randNum; // chooses a random number to see if loot os dropped- Loot chance
private Transform Epos; // enemy position


private void Start()
{
   // itemList = CamFollow.itemListPass;
    Epos = GetComponent<Transform>();
    Debug.Log(itemList);
}

public void DropItem()
{



        randNum = Random.Range(0, 101); // 100% total for determining loot chance;
        Debug.Log("Random Number is " + randNum);


        if (randNum >= 95) // Star Tablet drop itemList[2] currently
        {
            itemNum = 2;// grabs the star tab
            Instantiate(itemList[itemNum], Epos.position, Quaternion.identity);


        }
        else if (randNum > 75 && randNum < 95) // Extra life drop itemList[1] currently
        {

            itemNum = 1;// grabs the star tab
            Instantiate(itemList[itemNum], Epos.position, Quaternion.identity);

        }
        else if (randNum > 40 && randNum <= 75)// Health Heart drop itemList[0] currently
        {

            itemNum = 0;// grabs the star tab
            Instantiate(itemList[itemNum], Epos.position, Quaternion.identity);

        }


}// End of drop item
```

}

*********************************** Now in my EnemyDMG script: (BELOW)************************************

```
 public class EnemyDMG : MonoBehaviour
{
  private int enemyHP;
  private ItemDrop getItem;

private void Start()
{
    enemyHP = Random.Range(50, 200);
    getItem = GetComponent<ItemDrop>();


       }

      // Below this code is inside of a simple OnCollisionEnter2D() function
     // The enemy damage is calculated inside of this same function
     // so I decided not to add any source code not directly relevant to my question
        if(enemyHP <= 0)
        {
            if (getItem != null)
            {
                getItem.DropItem();
                Debug.Log("Dropped an Item " + getItem);
            }
            Destroy(gameObject);

        }
   }
```